# How to find out paper from phrases like "Chun and Seymour (1989)"?

Tags: research-process, research-undergraduate

I'm a senior college student and start to read papers for my final year project. I find phrases like " Chinn et all (1982)", "Garley et al(1978)" and  "Chun and Seymour (1989)". When I type those phrase in Google Scholar, its results are not relate to graph theory at all.

I'd like to know how to find papers from this phrases accordingly: )

Comment: You should find complete references at the end of the paper.  With this information, your librarian can help you find the papers themselves.

Comment: Another good resource for mathematics is [MathSciNet](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/index.html), if your institution subscribes.  Searching for author "Seymour" and year "1989", I found: MR1001391 Chung, F. R. K.; Seymour, P. D. Graphs with small bandwidth and cutwidth. Graph theory and combinatorics (Cambridge, 1988). Discrete Math. 75 (1989), no. 1-3, 113–119.  It also helps if you spell the author's name correctly ("Chung" not "Chun").

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Format `Chun and Seymour (1989)` means that there should be a full reference in the bibliography (at the and of the article, chapter or book; or sometimes in the footnote).

In case if it is missing, you can use [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/) with

```
author:Chun author:Seymour
```

then in the options set date range to `1988 -- 1990`.

Answer (score 1):

The way that I perform searches like this in Google Scholar, is to not only type in the citation (such as your examples), but also the main topic in inverted commas.

For example, if I take one of your examples:

> "Chun and Seymour, 1989" "Graph theory"

9 times out of 10, I find the article I am after (and more often than not, I find several more relevant papers).

Comment: Internationalization note: "inverted commas" = "quotation marks."

Comment: @aeismail - ah yes, thank you for that - completely did not think of the different terminology.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why people recommend searching Google Scholar or Mathscinet. Just try typing

```
Chun and Seymour (1989)
```

in Google. There are no obvious hits. But since it is supposed to be about graph theory, try typing this into Google:

```
Chun and Seymour (1989) graph theory
```

and the fourth hit is

```
Handbook of Graph Theory, Second Edition
https://books.google.co.nz/books?isbn=1439880182
Jonathan L. Gross, ‎Jay Yellen, ‎Ping Zhang - 2013 - ‎Mathematics
[ChSe89] F. R. K. Chung and P. D. Seymour, Graphs with small bandwidth and cutwidth, Discrete Mathematics 75 (1989), 113G119. ... Chung and W. T Trotter, Jr., Triangle—free graphs with restricted bandwidth, Progress in Graph Theory,  ...
```

so it looks like you should look for this:

```
F. R. K. Chung and P. D. Seymour, Graphs with small bandwidth and cutwidth, Discrete Mathematics 75 (1989)
```

googling which yields [this pdf](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~fan/wp/smallband.pdf) as the first result.